# GET запрос Retrofit 2

Tags: java, retrofit

Помогите разобраться с запросом Retrofit 2

```
@GET("Catalog_Номенклатура?$filter=Parent_Key eq guid'{guid}'&$select=Description,Code,Parent_Key&$format=json;odata=nometadata")
    Call<CatalogNomenclature> getValue(@Path("guid") String guid);
```

При попытке сделать этот запрос высыпается ошибка

```
URL query string "$filter=Parent_Key eq guid'{guid}'&$select=Description,Code,Parent_Key&$format=json;odata=nometadata" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
                                                                            for method ServisAPI.getValue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аннотация `Path` служит для динамического указания пути запроса. Вы же пытаетесь её использовать для динамического подставления параметров запроса, о чём вам и говорится в ошибке. Там же указано как именно надо делать:

```
@GET("Catalog_Номенклатура")
Call<CatalogNomenclature> getValue(@Query("$filter") String filter, @Query("$select") String select, @Query("$format") String format);
```

Вызывать как-то так:

```
getValue("Parent_Key eq guid" + guid, "Description,Code,Parent_Key", "json;odata=nometadata");
```